# "Well, no matter. Let's get on with the discussion."

Tags: meaning

If a professor says "Well, no matter. Let's get on with the discussion.", then which one is her intention?

a) To explain that she was only giving her opinion 
b) To indicate that the previous discussion was unimportant

The answer for the question above is b). 
Is there someone who can tell me the reason clearly? I'm still confused.

Comment: When I Google "no matter", the first three results (including the Google infobox!) clearly define "no matter".  What's still confusing about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without context, it only means that she wanted to stop discussing that topic and proceed to the next one.  Why?  A number of possible reasons (she was only giving her opinion, the previous topic was unimportant, she didn't want to waste time, it was time she went home, etc.)